# Showing entries that only have a specific category

Tags: channel-entries

With the category parameter in ExpressionEngine we can specify to not provide entries with a specific category `category="not 1"`

Is there a way to show entries that only have a specified category, for example: `category="only 1"`

So entries that are marked as category 1+2 will not show.

Comment: Good question. Are you asking in regard to the channel:entries tag or any tag? There is a very similar question here, and good info in the accepted (& other) answers:
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/excluding-a-category

I don't believe there are any native or non-work-around ways to do this. It's a pain. You could try a query or look for an add-on which does it.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a little bit of a rough work around but it should work for you.

Then you can use the "Entry Category Count" plugin and then run a conditional inside of your entries tag like the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" category="1"}
    {if {exp:entry_category_count entry_id="{entry_id}"} == "1"}
        ...
    {/if} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[Entry Category Count](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-category-count)

[On GitHub](https://github.com/erikreagan/er.entry_category_count.ee_addon)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would work - but it also looks as though would be pretty intensive performance wise. My question is purely hypothetical, so I'll wait to see what others come up with too.

Comment: Yep totally understand, "rough" may be an understatement lol :)

Comment: Haven't seen this approach before - good one!